# How to Install by ADB on Nokia 6300 4G?

Tags: android, adb, nokia, kaios

I have a Nokia 6300 4G running KaiOS. I've turned on ADB and USB Debugging on it. When I try to push an apk to the phone, it looks like it's working at first (it says a file gets pushed) but then it throws an error and nothing gets installed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my terminal output:

```
adb install myapp.apk
Performing Push Install
myapp.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 1.8 MB/s (42103965 bytes in 21.748s)
/system/bin/pm[6]: app_process: not found
```

Comment: `pm` is the central package manger. If this executable is missing you can't do anything. If it is present in a different path (search for it) you can try to `adb upload` the apk and then install it with the pm binary manually in an `adb shell`.

Comment: How do I search for it on my phone?

Comment: `adb shell` provides a standard shell like on Linux. So you can do `ls` or if it exists on the phone `find`. You will find plenty of tutorials how to use these programs, be aware that the binaries on Android may not support all options you read about here on Stackoverflow, Superuser or other tutorials.